# SQL Server add a column and populate multiple rows based on conditions across multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Timestamp          CPID    Con    Context    Type   Value
2018-01-01 03:11    1       2       6         8       0
2018-01-01 03:11    1       2       3         8       0
2018-01-01 03:11    1       2       3         3       100
2018-01-01 03:15    2       1       6         8       16
2018-01-01 03:15    2       1       3         8       15
2018-01-01 03:15    2       1       3         3       200
```

I want to add a column called `new_column`, and populate it with 1s when `Value=0` when `Context=6`. I want to consider Timestamp, CPID and Con as a group, so that when for a given group has `Context=6`, the other rows in that group are also assigned 1 in `new_column`. The result would look like this:

```
Timestamp          CPID    Con    Context    Type   Value    new_column
2018-01-01 03:11    1       2       6         8       0       1
2018-01-01 03:11    1       2       3         8       0       1
2018-01-01 03:11    1       2       3         3       100     1
2018-01-01 03:15    2       1       6         8       16      0
2018-01-01 03:15    2       1       3         8       15      0
2018-01-01 03:15    2       1       3         3       200     0
```

Notes: the row orders are not always the same, so I can't just fill down 2 rows every time; I also cannot directly ALTER Table because it is read only.

I'm still new to SQL so struggling with this one.

Comment: Having thse stored as a value seems like a bad idea, as if you change the value of 1 row, you may have to change the value of many. This would seem like a better candidate for a `VIEW`.

Comment: Also, if you can't change the definition of the table, because it's set to `READ ONLY` (i assume the database?) or you don't have permission, then you cannot add a column to the table anyway. A database must not be in `READ ONLY` mode for you to be able to make DDL changes to it, and you must have permission to `ALTER` the definition of the object(s) as well. If you do end up creating a `VIEW`, you'll need to do this in a different database if you can't make changes to the other, and use a cross database query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `view` by using `exists` :

```
select t.*,
      (case when exists (select 1 
                         from table t1  
                         where t1.Timestamp = t.Timestamp and t1.CPID = t.CPID and 
                               t1.Con = t.Con and (t1.Context = 6 or t1.Value = 0)
                        )
            then 1 else 0 
       end) as new_column
from table t;
```